# How to add a string to a specific line in a text file using C#

Tags: c#

i need your help,
i'm trying to add a string "MyString" to a specific line in a text file but couldn't yet.
for exmple
this is the content of my Text file :

```
First Name.
Last Name.
Date of Birth.
Counrty.
```

now what i'm looking for is add "MyString" will be "City" just in the next line after the word "Date of Birth". so the result can be like this :

```
First Name.
Last Name.
Date of Birth.
City.
Counrty.
```

I've tried:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\\Users\\Volki\\Desktop\\TextFile.txt", 
    string.Format("{0}{1}", "Date of Birth.", "City"));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212127/add-a-new-line-at-a-specific-position-in-a-text-file

Comment: I have added another approach to the problem in my edited answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Create `string[] currFile` and read from your file into it (you will get array with 4 elements in it)
- Create another `string[] newFile` but with size of `currFile.Length + 1`
- Copy `currFile` to `newFile` but forth line set to fifth (into new file you have first 3 lines, one empty and fifth line.
- Store city into `newFile`'s forth line
- Save that to text file

If i made some mistake post in comment, i set this up in hurry

EDIT:

What you probably do is use `Newtonsoft.Json` so you have class:

```
public User
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public DateTime dateOfBirth;
    public string Country;
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
public MyClass
{    

    public MyClass()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.FirstName = "User1";
        ...
        WriteUser(user);

        User user1 = ReadUser();
        string username = user1.FirstName;
    }

    void WriteUser(User user)
    {
        string stringToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        //Write this string to file
    }

    User ReadUser()
    {
        string stringFromFile = ...
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(stringFromFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll end up with two full copies of the file in memory doing this. It's possible to get it down to one line at a time, but even just one copy of the file would be better.

Comment: I have added another approach to the problem in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
string PathFile=@"c:\temp\testxx.TXT";

List<string> Listvalue = File.ReadAllLines(PathFile).ToList();
int IndexSearch = Listvalue.IndexOf("Date of Birth.");

if (IndexSearch>=0)
{
   Listvalue.Insert(IndexSearch+1, "City."); 
   File.WriteAllLines(PathFile, Listvalue.ToArray()); 
}
```

Comment: If the file is small it may work but it isn't a good idea to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: its a method... No limits are specified

Comment: But you can propose your better method ;)

Comment: The limit is the RAM!! I did it, take a look at my comment right up at the question.

Comment: lol he have a file, of course using database is a better idea, but its not the question...